# Inverse function problem. Why does $f(x)=x$?

Tags: functions

I have a problem from a textbook involving functions. The function $f(x)$ is defined by $f(x)=x^2-3$ for $[x\in\mathbb{R}, x\ge0]$. Here is the problem: Find the values of $x$ such that $f(x)={f^{-1}(x)}$. Obviously ${f^{-1}(x)}=\sqrt{x+3}$ for $[x\in\mathbb{R}, x\ge-3]$. Then, $f(x)={f^{-1}(x)}$, so $x^2-3=\sqrt{x+3}$, and I can solve this to find the solution.

However in the solution given by the textbook it is stated that $f(x)={f^{-1}(x)}$, then $f(x)=x$ and $x^2-3=x$, which gives the same solution. However, I do not understand why $f(x)=x$. How is this justified? I am sure that I am missing something obvious. To me it would seem that $ff(x)={ff^{-1}(x)}$ so ${f^{2}(x)}=x$.

Comment: @anonymouse I would vote for that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Migrated and expanded from a comment.*

Geometrically, you can think of inverting a function as reflecting it about the line $y = x$ (I'll leave the fuzzy details as to why to you; as a starting point, remember that the algebraic algorithm for inverting a function is "replace all the $x$'s with $y$'s and all the $y$'s with $x$'s").

If a function and its inverse have an intersection point, it **must** occur on the line $y = x$. This is because the only points that are fixed under reflection about $y = x$ are exactly the points on the line $y = x$. (Draw a point in the plane and reflect it to see where it ends up.)

So, the following are all equivalent:

$$f(x) = f^{-1}(x), f(x) = x, f^{-1}(x) = x$$

Comment: "If a function and its inverse have an intersection point, it must occur on the line  $y=x$"
Is this always true?  Suppose $f(x) = -x, f(x) = f^{-1} (x)$ for all $x.$

Comment: The correct statement is: if $f(x)=x$, then $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$. The converse does not hold in general.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=x^2-3$$
For clarity, let us denote, $$f(x)=y$$
Then,
$$y=x^2-3$$
$$x=\sqrt{y+3}=f^{-1}(y)$$
So, when you write,
$$f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x+3}$$
you are just interchanging the symbols of $y$ and $x$. Keeping the symbols as it is, it reduces to,
$$f(x)=x$$